Camera stops after one minute application suspend
I am using CameraX in my app. When I put application to background after one minute I got following logs and then when I resume the application the camera shows no preview (black screen).
Probably I have configured something wrong with my activity, but have now no idea what it is.
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

public class CustomLifecycle implements LifecycleOwner {

lifecycle = new CustomLifecycle();
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this.lifecycle, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);

This log is being diplayed all the time while the app is in the background:
D/SurfaceView@e6a8dbc: updateSurface: surface is not valid
I/SurfaceView@e6a8dbc: releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@99cd854[AndroidLauncher]

And after one minute this logs appears:
D/DeferrableSurface: use count-1,  useCount=1 closed=false androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@58a2ee3
D/DeferrableSurface: use count-1,  useCount=0 closed=false androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@f89dc55
D/DeferrableSurface: Surface no longer in use[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=1](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@f89dc55}
D/Camera2CameraImpl: CameraDevice.onError(): 0 failed with ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED while in OPENED state. Will attempt recovering from error.
E/Camera2CameraImpl: Error observed on open (or opening) camera device 0: ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED closing camera.

Then when I back to the app the camera shows no preview, but the whole app works fine.

Well... Probably solved.
Needed to change whole main activity part.
public class AndroidLauncher extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer, AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks {

And put LibGDX part to Fragment
arr = new ArrowGame(this, new AndroidInterfaceClass());
GameFragment lg = new GameFragment(arr);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
   add(R.id.linear1, lg).
   commit();

public class GameFragment extends AndroidFragmentApplication {
    AndroidLauncher al;
    ArrowGame arrowGame;

    public GameFragment(ArrowGame arrowGame) {
        this.arrowGame = arrowGame;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // return the GLSurfaceView on which libgdx is drawing game stuff
        return initializeForView(new ArrowGame(al, arrowGame, new AndroidInterfaceClass()));
    }
}

